# UITableView and UITableViewCell with dynamic height which is known only at WillDisplay

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, row-height

I have an `UITableView` with cells content of variable height. If works fine for autolayouted content but in my case the content is loaded (bound to UI) only when a cell is displayed (recycling, reuse, etc) so the only chance I can know the real `UITableViewCell` height is at `willDisplay` of my table dataSource.

At that point I already missed `EstimatedHeight` and `GetHeightForRow` stages.

Please advise, how I can change `UITableViewCell` height at `WillDisplay` stage

Answer (score 1):

If you set the AutoLayout right, and the cell should calculate Its own hight, It doesn't matter when and were you will change Its content/content height, It will know to adapt.
Check that the top of the cell content has a constraint to the top of the cells ContentView, and same for the bottom.

EstimatedHeight as the name says, is only an estimate. Meaning that you should have some implementation of trying to calculate the dataSource model object height, just a basic implementation.

Or you can run the application one time, and keep see how much is the cell height after Its calculates the height with AutoLayout, but this is much less "dynamic".

If a cell changes Its height after Its already set, you can call:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

And the cell will recalculate itself, instead of reloading the hole tableView.